# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in copycode.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click inspect element, I am getting error for copy clipboard tooltip:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Below is my JS code:

```
createtooltip()
var buddhaquote = document.getElementById('mytext')
buddhaquote.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    var selected = getSelectionText() // call getSelectionText() to see what was selected
    if (selected.length > 0){ // if selected text length is greater than 0
        var copysuccess = copySelectionText() // copy user selected text to clipboard
        showtooltip(e)
    }
}, false)
```

Comment: What about printing `budhaquote` variable in `console.log`? Or maybe just running `document.getElementById('mytext')` in console?

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Cannot read property 'XXX' of null.

means that you're working with variable that contains `null`. If you actually tried to debug your program and used `console.log`, you would see this that the variable `buddhaquote` contains null instead of the element you want.

This can have two causes, it's hard to tell because you decided not to share enough code.

1. HTML element with id `mytext` doesn't exist
2. You're trying to access element before it's created. For example this is wrong:

   ```
   <script>
       var test = document.getElementById("test");
       // Error: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.
       test.appendChild(new Text("Hello world!"));
   </script>
   <!-- only after this you can access span#test -->
   <span id="test"></span>
   ```

This is correct:

```
    <span id="test"></span>
    <script>
        var test = document.getElementById("test");
        test.appendChild(new Text("Hello world!"));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try envolve your code in

```
window.onload=function(){ --your code -- }
```

And check if you are not trying to get a **class** instead of **id**